# What change happens inside a molybdenum nucleus?

Tags: nuclear-physics

What happens/takes place in the molybdenum nucleus as it decays to Technetium-99 when a beta particle is emitted?

Comment: This question is too broad because "Molybdenum (42Mo) has 33 known isotopes, ranging in atomic mass from 83 to 115, as well as four metastable nuclear isomers. Seven isotopes occur naturally, with atomic masses of 92, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, and 100. All unstable isotopes of molybdenum decay into isotopes of zirconium, niobium, technetium, and ruthenium. "

Comment: If you would disclose which isotope you mean _and_ disclose your research efforts so far that would change the matter.

Comment: The isotope decays into 99Tc43

Comment: @my2cts I've rephrased the question

Comment: What is the relevance here of molybdenum?

Comment: @PM2Ring because it's the one decaying into tc-99

Comment: Ok, but you accepted Thomas's answer, which describes general beta minus decay, his answer isn't specifically about molybdenum.

Comment: @PM2Ring I didn't realize I had sorry. If you would like to submit an answer it would really benefit me and hopefully others, as I'm interested in this.

Comment: Thomas's answer is perfectly fine, I didn't mean you should un-accept it! His answer applies to any atom that undergoes beta minus decay, since they all work the same, only the half-life differs. If you want more details about the general process, see the Wikipedia article that he linked. Molybdenum-99 decays to technetium-99m, which is itself unstable. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technetium-99m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking more closely at the protons/neutrons which make up the molybdenum nucleus,
the following happens:

[image: Beta decay]
(image from [Wikipedia: Beta decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay))

One of the neutrons changes into a proton,
an electron and an anti-neutrino.
The proton stays inside the nucleus.
The electron and the anti-neutrino fly off with high energy.

$ n \rightarrow p + e^- + \bar{\nu}_e $